# React Apollo trigger query on componentWillLoad

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I want to be able to set up my Container with both Apollo queries and mutations and trigger them at will (not on Container export). It's easy for the mutations, but for some reason I can't figure it out for the queries (with parameter(s)). Here is what I have:

http://pastebin.com/pkr3L6TF

At this point it complains about not having a variable `id` passed at the bottom in the export call to `graphql`. How can I beat that get the same as with the mutation? I get a function from the `export graphql` and call it at will with `variables` parameters. How can you set up your query the same way?

Thanks

Comment: `withApollo` might be what you need: dev.apollodata.com/react/higher-order-components.html#withApollo

Comment: I have tried that route and ended up with an undefined result for my query. If you have good implementation example(s) using it, I'd love to see them though.

Comment: Once you have the `client`, you can call queries like that: https://github.com/graphcool-examples/exponent-auth0-example/blob/master/exponent-auth0/main.js#L79-L86